# syncing content between two qtextedits or a qtextedit and qscintilla with undo history

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4, qtextedit, qtextdocument

I'm writing a blog editor using pyqt4.  My issue is this.  There is a wysiwyg editor tab and a html code editor tab.  A change done in one should reflect in the other.  One option is to use the setHtml and toHtml functions whenever text changes in a qtextedit.  But the issue with this approach is that when I use setHtml on a qtextedit, all the previous edit undo history is lost.  If I try to maintain my own history on textchanged signal, lots of memory will be used.  Consider I enter a sentence, textchanged will be signaled for every single character and undo would be character by character.

I tried sharing the same qtextdocument between the two qtextedits but that also failed as highlighting is linked to the qtextdocument and hence is applied to both qtextedits.

Another option is to do nothing when the user works in the wysiwyg editor window.  When the user  makes some edit in the html code editor, I'll wait till the user finishes the edit and then once done, I'll find the diff of the edit and somehow, make a corresponding edit change in the wysiwyg editor's qtextdocument.  Is this achievable?  How can I do such a change in the qtextdocument?  Is there a more simple way that I am not aware of?

Please help.

Comment: What's the advantage to the user of showing both editors at once?

Comment: Well, the user would be editing in wysiwyg mode.  If they need to do a little tweaking that is not possible using the wysiwyg mode, then they can shift to the html code mode, do the necessary changes and shift back to the wysiwyg get mode.  All I need is to do the above functionality while maintaining history.

Comment: In my opinion you are over-complicating the gui in a way that is of little benefit to the user. The html editor is an "advanced" feature that should be in a separate window or tab.

Comment: Hi ekhumoro, that is one of the basic features of all blog editors.

Comment: Can you give an example? If so, it might give some clues about how to solve your problem. All of the ones I've seen are either wysiwyg or html, but not both at the same time.

Comment: Please checkout blogilo http://blogilo.gnufolks.org/ or Windows live writer (one of the few things that ms did right) http://explore.live.com/windows-live-writer

Comment: I stand by my earlier comments. With blogilo, the html editor is in a separate tab. This is probably true for all blog editors, and for good reason.

Comment: Yep, it is in a seperate tab.  But internally the changes done in one tab reflects in another and undo works seamlessly.

Comment: The issue is blogilo uses ktextedit which is more advanced than qtextedit.  but ktextedit is part of kdelib and not as portable as qt is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little more research and made my question more clear in [Accessing QTextHtmlImporter in PyQt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971095/accessing-qtexthtmlimporter-in-pyqt4)

That would essentially solve this issue.