# Accessing QTextHtmlImporter in PyQt4

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm writing a cross platform app in PyQt4.  For a particular feature, I would like to access the `QTextHtmlImporter` class of Qt4.  There is no direct python adapter class available in PyQt4.  The class is part of the src/gui/text/qtextdocumentfragment_p.h file.  Is there any way I can access that in Python?

I would like to modify `QTextDocument.setHtml()`, which code is:

```
void QTextDocument::setHtml(const QString &html) { 
    Q_D(QTextDocument); setUndoRedoEnabled(false); 
    d->clear(); 
    QTextHtmlImporter(this, html).import(); 
    setUndoRedoEnabled(true); 
}
```

to

```
void QTextDocument::setHtml(const QString &html) { 
    Q_D(QTextDocument); 
    QTextHtmlImporter(this, html).import(); 
}
```

Basically setting the HTML without clearing the history. I planned to do this by using a derived class of PyQt4's `QTextDocument` overriding the `setHtml` function. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QTextHtmlImporter` isn't even part of the Qt4 API, so the short answer is: no, there's no way to access it in PyQt4.

You could, of course, attempt to port the code to PyQt4, but I'm guessing that would be a non-trivial task.

The question is: why do you think you need to do this?

Why can't you use [QTextCursor.insertHtml](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtextcursor.html#insertHtml) or [QTextDocumentFragment.fromHtml](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtextdocumentfragment.html#fromHtml)?

**EDIT**

Here's an example of how to set the html in a text document without clearing the undo history:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.edit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        self.undo = QtGui.QPushButton('Undo')
        self.redo = QtGui.QPushButton('Redo')
        self.insert = QtGui.QPushButton('Set Html')
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.undo)
        layout.addWidget(self.redo)
        layout.addWidget(self.insert)
        self.undo.clicked.connect(self.edit.undo)
        self.redo.clicked.connect(self.edit.redo)
        self.insert.clicked.connect(self.handleInsert)
        self.edit.append('One')
        self.edit.append('Two')
        self.edit.append('Three')

    def handleInsert(self):
        cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(self.edit.document())
        cursor.select(QtGui.QTextCursor.Document)
        cursor.insertHtml("""<p>Some <b>HTML</b> text</p>""")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: How  QTextDocument.setHtml() works is like below
`void QTextDocument::setHtml(const QString &html)
{
    Q_D(QTextDocument);
    setUndoRedoEnabled(false);
    d->clear();
    QTextHtmlImporter(this, html).import();
    setUndoRedoEnabled(true);
}`
I would like to modify it to 
`void QTextDocument::setHtml(const QString &html)
{
    Q_D(QTextDocument);
    QTextHtmlImporter(this, html).import(); 
}`
Basically setting the html without clearing the history.  I planned to do this by using a derived class of PyQt4's QtextDocument overriding the setHtml function. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @Sharmila. I've updated my answer with a basic example of how to do this.

Comment: Wouldn't `cursor.select(QtGui.QTextCursor.Document)` do the same thing as the 2 calls to `movePosition` ?